# How do I know that scanner has read all the inputs?

Tags: java

If I allow the user to input numbers separated by spaces on a same line,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scan.next();
```

For example, if the user enters "1 2 3 4", it reads 1, 2, 3, and 4 one at a time. Is there any way that I can know when scanner has read all of them? It's crucial for the program I'm implementing.

Comment: @Einliterflasche for `System.in` `scan.hasNext()` will always be `true` as long as the stream remains open

Comment: Do I close the stream then? @QBrute

Comment: No.  The user would have to do that.  A better way is to use `scan.nextLine()` to read one line, and then open a second `Scanner`  taking that line as input.  Read until the end of "stream" on the second `Scanner` ... which will happen when your program has consumed everything on the line.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for `scanner.hasNext()`:

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.next();
System.out.println(input); 
 while(scanner.hasNext())
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
```

So here you are checking if there is next token available for scanner to process. If `Scanner.hasNext()` returns false means it has read all input token.